# Elisp how to write current coordinates to buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

So I have this function which gives me start and end position of selected text

```
(defun start-end (pos1 pos2)
 "…"
  (interactive "r")
  ; …
  (message "start: %d. end: %d." pos1 pos2)
)
```

Now I want to write to other file buffer named "result" (or create buffer if not exists), something like:

```
 pos1,pos2,param1,param2
```

where param1, param2 should be asked on cmd line. How do I make this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
(defun start-end (pos1 pos2 param1 param2)
  (interactive "r\nsParam1: \nsParam2: ")
  (message "%d,%d,%s,%s" pos1 pos2 param1 param2))
```

`interactive` supports a range of different input forms. You can separate them with newline:s to use more than one. In fact, you could supply an expression rather than a string, which is executed to perform any interactive action.

EDIT:

To create buffer you can use the following, it allows you to use all standard print function to insert anything in the new buffer:

```
(defun start-end (pos1 pos2 param1 param2)
  (interactive "r\nsParam1: \nsParam2: ")
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Result*"
    (princ (format "%d,%d,%s,%s" pos1 pos2 param1 param2))))
```

Comment: @Zdanozdan, see the addition in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to create a buffer (if it doesn't exist) then append the text you want to it:

```
(defun start-end (pos1 pos2)
  (interactive "nStart: \nnEnd: ")
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*start-end*"))
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert (format "start: %d. end: %d.\n" pos1 pos2)))
```

Comment: And you could use `format` instead of `message` if you don't want the information shown in the mini buffer and in `*messages*`.

Comment: To quote the docstring of switch-to-buffer: "WARNING: This is NOT the way to work on another buffer temporarily
within a Lisp program!  Use `set-buffer` instead.  That avoids
messing with the window-buffer correspondences.".  And often instead of `set-buffer` you're even better off using `with-current-buffer`.

Comment: @Moritz: Yeah I should have used format, forgot to change it.

Comment: @Stefan I don't know where you got that text from but it's not in the help for the function in my emacs (24.1.1). I would use with-current-buffer but this code switches to the buffer when done. It's up to the person asking the question to choose the behaviour they prefer.

Comment: @justinhj: Indeed, the warning was accidentally dropped from 24.1.  It'll be back in 24.3.